# How to implement hook_field_widget_form() for multiple fields?

Tags: entities

In a module I'm going to implement some Field types using Field API.
this is how hook_field_info() looks like in my module.

```
function myModule_field_info()
{
  return array(
    'type1' => array(
      'label' => t('Custom type 1'),
      'description' => t('Just for test'),
      'default_widget' => 'type1_textbox',
      'default_formatter' => 'type1_rawview',
    ),
    'type2' => array(
      'label' => t('Custom type 2'),
      'description' => t('Just for test'),
      'default_widget' => 'type2_textbox',
      'default_formatter' => 'type2_rawview',
    ),
  );
}
```

and the hook_field_widget_info() implementation is :

```
function myModule_field_widget_info()
{
  return array(
    'type1_textbox' => array(
      'label' => t('Text field'),
      'field types' => array('type1'),
    ),
    'type2_textbox' => array(
      'label' => t('Text field'),
      'field types' => array('type2'),
    ),
  );
}
```

off-course this is just an example and each widget has its especial form . now consider that each of my field types has more than one element .

- Field type 1

  - first name
  - last name
- Field type 2

  - phone number
  - address
  - email

now the question is how should I implement widget form for a multiple field type like this?

I tried this code but no chance :

```
function myModule_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
{
  if($field['cardinality'] == 1){
    $element['#type'] = 'fieldset';
  }
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'type1_textbox' :
      $type1 = array();
      $type1['firstName'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#field_prefix' => t('First Name : '),
        '#size' => 20,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['firstName']) ? $items[$delta]['firstName'] : '',
      );
      $type1['lastName'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#field_prefix' => t('Last Name : '),
        '#size' => 20,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['lastName']) ? $items[$delta]['lastName'] : '',
      );
      $element += $type1;
      break;
    case 'type2_textbox' :
      $type2 = array();
      $type2['phoneNumber'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#field_prefix' => t('Phone Number : '),
        '#size' => 20,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['phoneNumber']) ? $items[$delta]['phoneNumber'] : '',
      );
      $type2['address'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#field_prefix' => t('Address : '),
        '#size' => 60,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['address']) ? $items[$delta]['address'] : '',
      );
      $type2['email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#field_prefix' => t('Email : '),
        '#size' => 20,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['email']) ? $items[$delta]['type2']['email'] : '',
      );
      $element += $type2;
      break;
  return $element;
}
```

The code was edited and now no widget is shown in node-edit form and when I went to field management section this error is appearing

[image]

Comment: What you have looks correct...what do you mean by "no chance" exactly?

Comment: @Clive default_value does not show up on edit form :(

Comment: Oh right, `$items[$delta]['type2']['address']` needs to be `$items[$delta]['address']`, and similar for the rest. It's _so_ important to include what's actually wrong in your question

Answer (score 0):

the name of the form in   myModule_field_widget_form must be the same column in your  .install file  make sure it matches the same  column